# drupal ubercart membership functionality

Tags: ubercart, users

In a drupal site i had defined three packages for a users.
And i want to achive two functionality as :

1. I want user to be able to purchase only one package at a time, and
2. Users will be not able to add another package if already a package
   exist in the cart or if  he already had bought a package.

Kindly suggest the way of implementing the functionality.